# Why my recursion doesnt work? (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I want to find the Lowest Commone Ancestor of a binary tree (not a binary search tree!) To this end I use the second method from this web page: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-binary-tree-set-1/ 
Basically, in Java my method looks like this:

```
  private static int LCA2(Node root, Node n1, Node n2)
  {
    if(root == null) return -1;

    if(root.id == n1.id || root.id == n2.id) return root.id;

    int left = LCA2(root.left, n1, n2);
    int right = LCA2(root.right, n1, n2);

    if(left != -1 && right != -1) return root.id;

    if(left != -1) return LCA2(root.left, n1, n2);

    return LCA2(root.right, n1, n2);
}
```

And this is the `main()` function:

```
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
        List<Node> tree = new ArrayList<Node>();

        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        Node n2 = new Node(2);
        Node n3 = new Node(3);
        Node n4 = new Node(4);
        Node n5 = new Node(5);
        Node n6 = new Node(6);
        Node n7 = new Node(7);
        Node n8 = new Node(8);
        Node n9 = new Node(9);

        n1.left = n2;
        n1.right = n3;
        n2.left = n4;
        n2.right = n5;
        n5.left = n6;
        n3.left = n8;
        n3.right = n7;
        n8.right = n9;

        res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int k = 2;

//      findKNodes(n1, k);
//      for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
//          System.out.print(res.get(i) + " ");

        int res = LCA2(n1, n4, n6);

        System.out.println(res);

    }
```

Basically my tree looks like this:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
 / \  /\
4  5  8 7
  /   \
 6     9
```

And I run my recursive function `LCA(Node root, node n1, node n2)` with root = 1, n1 = 4, n2 = 6; So after the first recursive call of `LCA` I expect the finction to return `left = 4`, `right = -1` and to recurse on the left subtree of the root. However it returns `left = 6`, `right = -1`, which is not a problem for the very first iteration, but for the next it goes to infinity cycle and I dont know how to fix this.

EDIT: the code for class Node:

```
public static class Node
{
    int id;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node (int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this correct: n5.left = n6;? Also, you have n1.right = n3; twice in the snippet.

Comment: yes, n5.left = n6; I will remove the second n1.right = n3

Comment: That is not correct according to your tree.

Comment: Just an observation. Towards the end of the function, instead of calling LCA2 again, you can might as well just return the left and right nodes respectively.

Comment: @JamesB In the snippet I have written 'n5.left = n6;' also in the drawing of the tree node 6 is a left child of node 5. what is not correct?

Comment: @user1990169 OK, but then how I will tell the function to recurse on the left or on the right subtree?

Comment: Can you also give us the code for `class Node` ?

Comment: I guess, in the second LCA2(root.left, n1, n2); you meant LCA2(left, n1, n2); ???

Comment: @user3371223 lol apologies, IE has not rendered your tree diagram correctly, all looks good in Chrome!

Comment: @user1990169 No, the variable `left` is of type `int` and to call method `LCA2` I need type `Node`. `int left` is just a variable that if it is positive indicates that either  node `n1` or `n2` is in the left subtree while `root.left` is the root of the left subtree

Comment: @user3371223 OK, but there is no point in calling LCA2 with the same input parameters again. You have already calculated the value and it is stored in your variable left.

Comment: Hmm, your code run correctly on my computer, after I remove this line `res = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: @user1990169 I corrected what you said but the problem is still the same. Let me explain more detailed: on the very first call of my fincyion it recurse several times, till it reaches node 4, and thus it sets `left = 4`; However the next line of the code is `Node right = LCA2(root.right, n1, n2);` so it recurse again, this time with `root = 2` and on this recursion it resets `left = 6` and returns `right = null/ right = -1`. How should I recurse s.t. the next recursion levels do not change mine `left` element, or I should not bother about this?

Comment: @user3371223 hmm, so you still go into a infinite loop? so there are two chances, one is the code here and your code are different, second is you should recompile your code? because your code here definitely cannot compile. And what user1990169 suggest is only to optimize your code, because in the end, you should not call same method twice (like what you currently did)

Comment: @PhamTrung, I see thanks, I recompiled and it works now. The recursive calls are still not clear for me, so if someone can explain, it will be very nice

Comment: @user3371223 added my answer to explain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got a answer by @Khaled and @Pham Trung but let me help you to clear the recursive call trace.

```
    1. LCA2(1, 4, 6) -> left = LCA2(2, 4, 6) = 2 (by 2 step because left = 4 != -1 and right = 6 != -1 means root.id is LCA which is 2)
                        right = LCA2(3, 4, 6) = -1 

    2. LCA2(2, 4, 6) -> left = LCA2(4, 4, 6) = 4 (by 2a step)
                        right = LCA2(5, 4, 6) = 6 (by 2b step)

    2a. LCA2(4, 4, 6) -> return root.id which is 4
    2b. LCA2(5, 4, 6) -> left = LCA2(6, 4, 6) = 6(by 2ba step)
                         right = LCA2(null, 4, 6) = -1  

    2ba. LCA2(6, 4, 6) -> return root.id which is 6
```

As a final call 2 != -1 so it returns 2 as a answer.
Please revert if you need more clarification.
You can find java code for tree problems of geeksforgeeks in following URL if you are stuck.
https://github.com/harmishlakhani/AlgoAndDataStructure/blob/master/AlgoAndDataStructure/src/com/ds/tree/BinaryTreeUtility.java

Answer (score 2):

Note: After fixing issue about recompiling the code (which I has mentioned in my comment), here is the tip to help your code run faster.

To avoid calling the same method `LCA2` twice, you should rewrite your method as follow:

```
private static int LCA2(Node root, Node n1, Node n2)
{
    if(root == null)
        return -1;

    if(root.id == n1.id || root.id == n2.id)
        return root.id;

    int left = LCA2(root.left, n1, n2);
    int right = LCA2(root.right, n1, n2);

    if(left != -1 && right != -1)
        return root.id;

    if(left != -1)
        return left; // you don't need to call the same routine again here, which will cost you some time.

    return right; //Similar reason

}
```